# PHP - Funcionamiento extraño de ancla dentro de formulario

Tags: php, html

Consulta. En un sistema de carrito implementé un formulario para mandar por POST algunos datos. Dentro de este form, tengo un enlace [a href] para cada producto, para que el usuario pueda quitarlo del carrito si asi lo desea. El problema es que sucede algo muy raro. Si yo hago click en este enlace para quitar uno de los productos no funciona como deberia, funciona como el boton submit, es decir, se envian los datos por post. En cambio si por ejemplo, hago click derecho en ese enlace y luego en "Abrir nueva pestaña" si funciona como debería. Como solucionarlo?

De mas esta decir que quito las etiquetas de  si funciona como debería. El código de cada enlace es el siguiente:

```
<?php echo "<a href='./cart.php?takeOff=" . key($array) . "' title='Quitar del Carrito' class='align-self-start'>";?>
```

Comment: Hola Mauri, ¿podrías colocar el código del formulario y del _Backend_ que la procesa?. Por otro lado, te invito a [Realizar un recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Te ganarás una medalla. Por otro lado, te invito también a consultar sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No es raro lo que ocurre. Cuando pones una URL así: `cart.php?takeOff=...etc` estás enviando datos al servidor (por GET, no por POST para aclarar). Te aconsejo que para evitar esto implementes Ajax, así, puedes poner un botón, un click, lo que quieras, escuchar los clicks en esos elementos y mandar a quitarlos vía Ajax. Cualquier URL que pongas como lo tienes ahora remitirá los datos sí o sí al servidor, a no ser que apliques redirecciones vía `.htaccess`. Para casos como estos lo mejor es Ajax, porque además puedes actualizar el DOM ahí mismo, quitando el elemento sin recargar la página.

Comment: Cedano entonces el hecho de que funcione distinto si abro una nueva pestaña o no se debe a que es una peticion por GET? Voy a tener que aprender ajax